# How to make ref in component link to component data?

Tags: vue.js

I am using https://github.com/r3code/vue-vis-network 
I am getting error: `Cannot read property 'hasChildNodes' of undefined`

My component code is:

```
<template>
    <el-container >
            <el-main>
                <network ref="network" :nodes="nodes" :edges="edges" :options="options"> </network>                        
                <button @click="get_data">GetData</button>
            </el-main>
  </el-container>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        components: { Notification },
        data () {
            return {
              nodes: [],
              edges: [],
              options: []
            }
        },

        methods:
        {
          get_data()
          {
            axios.get(base_url + '/graph')
               .then((response) => {
                this.nodes = response.data.nodes;
                this.edges = response.data.edges;
                }).catch((error) => {   console.log(error); });  
          }
        },
    }
</script>
```

index.js:

```
Vue.component('network', new vueVisNetwork.Network);
```

I suppose that there is problem that it's attempt to access to data placed in #app. How I can say him that he should use data declared in component?

Actual data example:

```
  nodes : [
    {id: 1, label: 'Fooo"', group: "company"},
    {id: 2, label: 'Baaar', group: "owner"},
  ],


  edges : [
    {from: 1, to: 2},
  ],
```

possible related issue https://github.com/crubier/react-graph-vis/issues/57

Comment: What are the actual values of this.nodes and this.edges?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I have updated question with data example